# How to load components in a loop passing the properties of an object as props?

Tags: reactjs

I want to render this component in a loop:

```
<OptionsFly title={prop} text={prop}></OptionsFly>
```

Depending on the number of objects that this array has:

```
   let options = [{
        title: "Regala ",
        text: "Sorprende ",
    }, {
        title: "Marc",
        text: " sorpresa",
    }];
```

That is, I want to load the component twice, and pass the corresponding attributes as props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` function to do an action for every element of the array.

```
     <>
        {options.map((el, i) => 
           <OptionsFly key={`${el.title}_${i}`} title={el.title} text={el.text} />
        )}
     </>
```

Comment: @Marc Please let me know if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

you could map over it and every time you render your component, like this

```
   const xNumberOfYouComponent=options.map((option,index)=>{
   return( 
   <div key={index}>
   //you will loop through every single item inside your options array 
   <OptionsFly title={option.title} text={option.text}></OptionsFly>
   </div>
   }
```